# How to get an item from Model without calling a foreach loop in View MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, view

I only have access to the data when calling the `@foreach(var item in Model)` loop.
`@Model.` or `Html.DisplayFor()` doesn't seem to work because it doesn't "see" it. Any other ideas how to display data?

Edit:
Model

```cs
namespace Model.EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("Urlaubantrag")]
    public class Urlaubantrag
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Jahr { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]        
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Gültiges Datum erwartet")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Datum_von { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]     
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Gültiges Datum erwartet")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Datum_bis { get; set; }

        public decimal Tage { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the model please? Or a similar setup? You can always use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item

Comment: shouldn't it be `@item.`

Comment: @RemarkLima I edited the question with my shortened Model . My problem is that I don't have any access to anything unless I use the foreach loop. In other Model I can use Html.DisplayFor()

Comment: @Eden and the model into the page is a `List<Urlaubantrag>`?

Comment: @RemarkLima its `@model PagedList.IPagedList<Model.EF.Urlaubantrag>`

Comment: So @Eden you have a list of objects, so if it's a single object you can pass in `@model Model.EF.Urlaubantrag` and change the controller to pass the single object. Or if it's supposed to be a list then you can call `@Model.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item.